# Difference between Java's PriorityQueue constructor call and addAll method

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I was solving a problem on leetcode and someone told me that instantiation of a PriorityQueue with a collection takes O(n) time and the addAll method takes O(nlogn) time. Is this correct? 
I could not find any proofs for this.

https://www.techiedelight.com/find-kth-largest-element-array/ this website on the 3rd approach uses addAll(List) to create a PriorityQueue is it really O(n)?

Comment: I have never used a priority queue. Can you describe its algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

[PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in java gets the addAll method from the [AbstractQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)). The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) says that the addAll method just iterates through the supplied Collection. So I'd say addAll takes O(n) time. Take a look at [the source code](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/AbstractQueue-source.html) if you're not convinced.